# Receiving "No Module named ''taggit" in Django3

Tags: django, django-taggit, modulenotfounderror

```
                              New to django, attempting to add tagging functionality to a blog application.
```

This is a debian environment.

Installed using pip3 install django-taggit

validated using pip freeze
Django==3.
django-taggit==1.2.0

Then added taggit to Installed_APPS in settingss.py

Django then responds  with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit

'

Comment: Make sure you are activating any virtual environment you have and have installed the package inside this virtual environment.

Comment: If you copied the ModuleNotFoundError as-is, maybe the 'taggit' string in INSTALLED_APPS has a linefeed at the end.